# Gradle batch task that invokes subproject and other tasks in order

Tags: gradle

I am writing gradle 1.4 build file for multimodule project. So there is root **build.gradle** that defines something like:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    ...
```

which defines **build** task for all submodules. Submodules are included in **settings.gradle** and each module has its build file with defined dependencies.

Everything by-the-book, so far:) Now, in the main build file I've added some additional project-scope tasks, like: *aggregateJavadoc* (collects all javadocs into one) or *bundleJar* (creates bundle jar from all classes), etc. Each on works when invoked manually.

Now I need a task **release** that will

- build all submodules (as invoked from command line - meaning, i dont want to manually write execute() for each submodule)
- invoke additional tasks (using execute() I presume).

I tried **dependsOn** but the order of listed tasks is not followed. Also, dependent modules seems to be executed after release task execution. I tried several other ideas and failed.

Question: what would be the best way to create such *batch task*, that has to invoke something on all submodules and additionally to perform some more tasks? What would be the best gradle-friendly solution? Thanx!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It happened that this can be solved with simple dependency management.

So, we have many modules. Now, lets create additional tasks that depends on modules being build:

```
task aggregateJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    dependsOn subprojects.build

task bundleJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn subprojects.build
```

Finally, our `release` task would simply look like this:

```
task release() {
    dependsOn subprojects.build
    dependsOn aggregateJavadoc
    dependsOn bundleJar
    ...
}
```

This will build subprojects first; not because it is listed first, but because additional tasks depends on building. Order of additional task is not important. This make sense the most to me.

EDIT
if one of your subprojects (i.e. modules) is non-java module, then you will have a problem building this project. What I do is to group submodules, like this:

```
def javaModules() {
    subprojects.findAll {it.name.contains('jodd-')}
}
```

and then instead to refer to `subprojects`, use `javaModules` everywhere! For example:

```
configure(javaModules()) {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    ...
```

and

```
task prj {
    dependsOn javaModules().build
}
```

btw, I am using this 'dummy' task `prj` for `dependsOn` on all those additional projects that depends on building, to prevent repeating.

Comment: I created a "release" task that calls "dependsOn subprojects.build". This works perfectly except a subproject I have that is a non-java project. I however created a task called build for that project yet it complains, "Could not find property 'build' on project ':native'."

Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, I've bumped to the same thing as i have one non-java module. Please read my EDIT of the answer for thoughts.

Comment: I already organize the subprojects by type, however, i want to invoke the same task definition on the projects. For whatever reason the task is not available as a property for the project, which according to the documentation, it should be.

Comment: I guess because the task was defined in my subproject (near the bottom) and the "release" task was a root task (defined near the top of my file) it wasn't finding it. When I moved the release task below my project definitions, it works.