# Dependency on subprojects' war task

Tags: gradle

I have following structure:

```
./build.gradle
./api
./api/build.gradle
./web
./web/build.gradle
./other
./other/build.gradle
```

both **api** and **web** projects use `war` plugin, but **other** project has only `java` plugin.

I want to define a task for heroku in root project, that would say:

- execute **clean** task on all subprojects that have it
- execute **war** task on all subprojects that have it
- execute **build** task on all subprojects that have it

I saw this answer: [Gradle batch task that invokes subproject and other tasks in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604266/gradle-batch-task-that-invokes-subproject-and-other-tasks-in-order)
but it fails. Tried following configuration

```
task stage() {
    dependsOn subprojects.clean
    dependsOn subprojects.war
    dependsOn subprojects.build
}
```

And get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'baltona-mdm'.
> Could not find property 'war' on project ':api'.
```

(api **has** `war` plugin, and if I uncomment task stage, I can run `gradle :api:war`)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for error:

```
Could not find property 'war' on project ':api'
```

was to use

```
evaluationDependsOnChildren()
```

However, for the problem in the title I have come up with something like that:

```
task stage() {

    subprojects.each({p ->
            dependsOn p.clean
        if(hasWarTask(p)) {
            dependsOn p.war
        } else {
            dependsOn p.build
        }
    })
}

private boolean hasWarTask(Project p) {
    !p.getTasksByName("war", false).isEmpty()
}
```

I don't like it, so if anyone has better solution, I'm open for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle doesn't currently have first-class support for declaring workflows such as clean -> war. The simplest solution is to just execute `gradle clean war`. Another solution is to manipulate `gradle.startParameter.taskNames`. For example, you could look for a `stage` task name and replace it with task names `clean` and `build`.

Implementing workflows using task relationships (`dependsOn`, `mustRunAfter`, etc.) is more difficult. Your proposed solution above doesn't guarantee that in the context of `stage`, clean tasks run before all other tasks.

PS: `build` depends on `war`, so you might not have to handle both cases. `evaluationDependsOnChildren()` can be avoided by deferring `dependsOn` task resolution (e.g. `dependsOn { p.war }`).